# Are there other C standard library functions like memcmp that have timing side-channel risk?

Tags: c, memcmp, c-standard-library, timing-attack, side-channel-attacks

I found that `memcmp()` will return false earlier if the first byte is different in both strings, and I thought it has a timing attack risk. However, when I tried to find out if there were other functions that had side-channel risks like `memcmp`, I couldn't find any information.

Comment: `strpbrk()`, `strspn()`, `strcspn()`, `strcmp()`, `strstr()`, `strncmp()`, `strcmp()`, `strchr()` (but probably not `strrchr()`) — all of those stop at the first match, so they are vulnerable to timing side-channel attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `strcmp` and friends all work the same way. If in the rare case you are timing attack sensitive you have to write all your own comparison loops. The compiler can quite often optimize them back into timing sensitive loops now too, so you end up compiling such files with -O0. I know, so sad.

Typically you don't have this problem because you compare hashes.

Comment: _"Typically you don't have this problem because you compare hashes"_ - Can you put that in glowing gold somehow? :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: No. I have eye problems that force me to use color leveling code. So even if there were a way to change colors in markdown I don't know it nor can I use it.

Comment: Seems like we have similar issues. The actual coloring scheme was chosen by me since it's often used to praise and emphasize.

Comment: @Joshua -O0 is not necessary. There is `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @Joshua Do similar functions of memcmp also have these problems? Is there a comprehensive list of side channel risk functions?

Comment: @zhxf7481: Assume all conditional functions have side channel attacks unless documented otherwise.